# Multiple \label's error in align environment

Tags: errors, equations, numbering, align

Here is the minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}



\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \nonumber \label{SR1} &\text{Rho-DNA} \mathrel{\mathop{\longrightarrow}^{k_1}} \text{Rho}\quad&&\text{SR1} \\
        \nonumber \label{SR2} &\text{Rho} + \text{GDP} \mathrel{\mathop{\longrightarrow}^{k_2}} \text{Rho-GDP}\quad&&\text{SR2} \\
        \nonumber \label{SR3} &\text{Rho-GDP} + \text{GDI} \mathrel{\mathop{\longleftrightarrow}^{k_3}_{k_4}} \text{Rho-GDI}\quad&&\text{SR3} \\
        \nonumber \label{SR4} &\text{Rho-GDP} + \text{GTP} \mathrel{\mathop{\rightarrow}^{k_5}} \text{Rho-GTP} + \text{GDP}\quad&&\text{SR4} \\
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```

The error I get is:

```
line 0: Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'SR1' will be lost
line 0: Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label 'SR3' will be lost
```

What is the issue?

Comment: `\nonumber` in conjunction with `\label` is not *really* useful

Comment: the `\quad&&\text{SR1}`like pieces look like an attempt for custom tags to me. If that is right you could instead use `\tag{SR1}` (and remove `\nonumber`). Then both the error goes away and you can actually refer to the equations.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sure, it was just an experiment.

Comment: You might also like to take a look at the `mhchem` or the `chemformula` package.

Comment: @cgnieder oops I just noticed your comment is same as my answer I'll delete (but that is the answer:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was (or rather am) waiting for confirmation if my hunch about the custom tags is right or not...

Comment: @close-voters: the question is less than 1 hr old! _#toosoon_

Comment: @cgnieder You are totally right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using the wrong tool for this purpose.

Either use a tabular, if you want a unique number, or `align` together with `\tag` if you want the labels to be considered like equation numbers.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\ch{"Rho-DNA"          ->[$k\sb1$]          "Rho"}             & \text{SR1} \\
\ch{"Rho" + "GDP"      ->[$k\sb2$]          "Rho-GDP"}         & \text{SR2} \\
\ch{"Rho-GDP" + "GDI" <->[$k\sb3$][$k\sb4$] "Rho-GDI"}         & \text{SR3} \\
\ch{"Rho-GDP" + "GTP"  ->[$k\sb5$]          "Rho-GTP" + "GDP"} & \text{SR4}
\end{tabular}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
&\ch{"Rho-DNA"          ->[$k\sb1$]          "Rho"}             \tag{SR1}\label{SR1} \\
&\ch{"Rho" + "GDP"      ->[$k\sb2$]          "Rho-GDP"}         \tag{SR2}\label{SR2} \\
&\ch{"Rho-GDP" + "GDI" <->[$k\sb3$][$k\sb4$] "Rho-GDI"}         \tag{SR3}\label{SR3} \\
&\ch{"Rho-GDP" + "GTP"  ->[$k\sb5$]          "Rho-GTP" + "GDP"} \tag{SR4}\label{SR4}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]